# Aumann's paper unknown notation

Tags: game-theory

I'm reading an Aumann's [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1103038400) about Games of perfect information. I do not follow the notation on page 414 in the Definition 10.1: $$e(f_k^i(y))=(i)$$

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Is it the $(i)$ that is the issue here?

Comment: @ClementC.Mainly the $e$.